# sqoop Import lastmodified gives duplicate records. It does'nt merger

Tags: hive, sqoop

I am facing a kind of wierd issue. Most of places I found that when lastmodified is used old and new files will be merged to remove duplicated. How ever in my case it is not happening.

- I used :

  `sqoop import --connect "jdbc:mysql://<hostname>:3306/<dbname>" --username root -password password --table  LoginRoles --hive-import --create-hive-table --hive-table LoginRoles --hive-delims-replacement " "`

Table got created and data was loaded properly in `/user/hive/warehouse` location.

```
LoginRoleId LoginRole   CreatedDate             ModifiedDate

1       admin1  2013-09-30 14:21:28 2013-09-30 16:03:39
2       admin2  2013-09-30 14:36:23 2013-09-30 15:53:19
3       admin3  2013-09-30 14:39:13 2013-09-30 14:39:13
4       admin5  2013-09-30 14:40:55 2013-09-30 14:40:55
```

- Now I ran below query and Modified date got updated to `'2013-09-30
  17:03:44'`

`update loginroles set ModifiedDate=now(),loginrole="admin4" where LoginRoleID=4;`

- When I ran the job as below using `Sqoop job -exec mymodified`

`sqoop job --create mymodified -- import --connect "jdbc:mysql://<hostname>:3306/<dbname>" --username root -password password --table LoginRoles --hive-import --hive-table LoginRoles --hive-delims-replacement " " --check-column ModifiedDate --incremental lastmodified --last-value '2013-09-30 16:03:39'`

I see total 5 rows in hive as below.

```
1   admin1  2013-09-30 14:21:28.0   2013-09-30 16:03:39.0   
4   admin4  2013-09-30 14:40:55.0   2013-09-30 17:03:44.0
2   admin2  2013-09-30 14:36:23.0   2013-09-30 15:53:19.0
3   admin3  2013-09-30 14:39:13.0   2013-09-30 14:39:13.0
4   admin5  2013-09-30 14:40:55.0   2013-09-30 14:40:55.0
```

I am sure I am missing something important and subtle.

Version details of sqoop used 
`Sqoop 1.4.3-cdh4.3.0
git commit id 7a52f9aa97cba43aae8b700f7e93f97dcdb0b21a
Compiled by jenkins on Mon May 27 20:33:21 PDT 2013`

Comment: Hi All, This approach does not work at this point of time. I have posted in cloudera google group and for now this wont work. I will have to use workaround to create staging folders and cleaning them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach does not work at this point of time. I have posted in cloudera google group and for now this wont work. I will have to use workaround to create staging folders and cleaning them. Below link helped me to solve the issue.

http://himanshubaweja.com/post/7529434265/analytics-reached-mysql-limit-lets-hive